# What should we do with very specific questions that cannot be made general?

Tags: discussion

[Breathing and Leg Fatigue while running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/29651/breathing-and-leg-fatigue-while-running)

This is a very specific question I'm not sure to what extent it is suitable for SE as it is extremely unlikely that anyone would benefit from the answer apart from the OP.

I cannot see a way to make this a useful question for PF users?

Answer (score 1):

That used to be addressed with a "Too localized" close reason, however, that was removed due to misunderstanding of it and abuse. [There is an interesting meta discussion on it as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

While this may be applicable to only a small segment of our intended audience, are we here only to answer questions that we deem interesting? Or to answer questions that may help people improve their fitness? In the case of this question, I found it bordeline to be asking for medical advice. When you answered it, you are signifying that you find it interesting enough to provide an answer. And, if the only answer you can give is to see a doctor, then you should be VTC instead of answering.

Comment: As may be made clear, I voted to close after submitting my answer and having it rebuked. I saw value in answering to give more options/possibilities of the cause and information for someone with a similar issue in future that stumbles upon this. I read the question as "what are the potential reasons that I get fatigued more than expected doing uphill/squats" which has many great answers as opposed to how the question has now turned out.

Comment: @JJosaur - Unfortunately, even the "What are the potential reasons" wouldn't make a great question either, because that would produce a lot of spaghetti throwing to see what sticks. "Well it could be A, or maybe be" "Don't forget about C and D", "My cousin's sisters nieces friend had E", etc.